# Saving entity from parent to a child Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud-repository

Hello I am trying to understand how can I made a record in db with entity from another entity repository.

Example I have

```
public class Busstop {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "busstop")
private Bus bus;
}
```

Same for bus entity:

```
public class Bus {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "busstop_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_busstop_bus_id"))
private Busstop busstop;
```

Now when I call `busstopService.save(busstop);` I want to make a record also in bus table with the attached bus in the busstop dto with is not existing in the databse.
Note: I don't want bus id to be present in the bbusstop table.

I am new to Spring boot.Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I make a search online and I found that I need to use `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` on the`@OneToMany` mapping.